# Process html form to php file but stay on html page

Tags: php, html

I have **index.html**, where my **POST method** form is.
Second file is **process.php** file where all my variables are.

How can I after click on "submit" process informations from form to process.php page, but still remain at my homepage (index.html).

With "default" settings, it redirect me to aforementioned PHP page.

Comment: Google search [**php ajax form**](https://www.google.com/?q=php+ajax+form&gws_rd=cr&ei=-N4UWZrYCIO1sQGT26yYCw)

Comment: As @Mi-Creativity said -AJAX!

Comment: Old school is to set the action of your from to the same page and catch your POST variables, do stuff and decide the course of action. Ajax is new school.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with form in the same page by adding a condition like :

```
if(isset($_POST['SomeVariableFromForm'])){    // check if a variable from form is sent

       include process.php;   // include your variables file


      // some function

}
```

Remember to change the direction of the form to index.php

Also change your file name from  `index.html` to `index.php`

You can learn more about ISSET here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

i think what you really need there is sending an AJAX request

take a look at the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple, non-AJAX solution, add this to the end of your `process.php` file:

```
header("Location: index.html");
die();
```

Optionally, if you want to return a certain message or use certain variables from `process.php`, you could use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX :)
If you're using jQuery, it's extremely simple:

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(){
  $.post("process.php", $(this).serialize(), function(result){
    /* do something with whatever you echo with PHP here */
  });
  return false; /* prevent page from refreshing */
});
```